# JQuery not appending properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I'm trying to load some XML using the `JQuery.load` function, and that bit is going fine. I'm loading the XML and putting it into the DOM, which is what I want. However, I then need to iterate through the top level child elements and append certain nodes to a different Container. All will become clear when you see the below code:

this is my JS and the storage element:

```
<div id="ProjectLoad" style="display:none"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $('#ProjectLoad').load('projects.xml');


            $('project').each(function(){
                debugger;
                var name = $(this).children('name').first().text();
                var desc = $(this).children('desc').first().text();
                var created = $(this).children('created').first().text();
                var uri = $(this).children('url').first().created();

                $('#trapezoidContainer').append('<div id="' + name + '" class="trapezoid-container"></div>');

                $('#' + name).append('<div id="sub-' + name + '" class="trapezoid"></div>');

                $('#sub-' + name).append('<a href="' + uri + '">' + name + '</a>');

                $(this).hover(function(){
                    $('#title').text(name);
                    $('#description').text(desc);
                })

            })
        </script>
```

And this is my projects.xml:

```
<projects>
    <project>
        <name>Test</name>
        <desc>Simple test project</desc>
        <created>17/11/1998</created>
        <url>http;//www.gitlab.com/roconnor/test</url>
    </project>
</projects>
```

I have a debugger statement in the `.each()`, but it isn't being hit, which is making me thing the `.load()` is executing *after* the `.each()` due to latency...

Comment: ".load() is executing after the .each()". No, `load` is executed sooner but the data hasn't been returned yet. You should use the `callback` function of the `load` method. This is an asynchronous process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the complete option in load-

```
$('#ProjectLoad').load('projects.xml', function() {
 //just after the end of loading
$('project').each(function(){
                debugger;
//and so on
});
```

[source](https://api.jquery.com/load/)